# Accessing apache on a vagrant sandbox using ssl (port forwarding)

Tags: ssl, virtualbox, portforwarding, vagrant

I've built a vagrant/virtualbox web server as a development sandbox, and configured apache in the VM for ssl (on the default port 443, with a self-signed certificate). I've tested pages on the VM itself using curl

```
curl -v -k https://mysite.mydomain.com/testSearch/results?postcode=WN8+0BA
```

and it seems to work quite happily, so I'm satisfied that apache is correctly configured and working in the VM.

However, when I try to access the VM from my host's browsers over https, I'm unable to do so.

I've added

```
config.vm.forward_port "https", 443, 8443
```

to my vagrantfile, but trying to access the url

```
https://mysite.mydomain.com:8443/testSearch/results?postcode=WN8+0BA
```

simply can't display the page I've tried with several different browsers: IE gives a meaningless "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"; Chrome gives

```
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

Firefox gives me

```
An error occurred during a connection to mysite.mydomain.com:8443.
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

but even the Firebug Net tab doesn't tell me anything more than that.

I'm not getting anything in the access or error logs on the VM apache, so I suspect that vagrant isn't forwarding the ssl at all.

- VM Guest OS: centos56x64
- Host: Windows 7 64-bit
- JRuby: 1.6.3 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-07-07 965162f) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_24) [Windows 7-amd64-java]
- Vagrant: 0.7.8
- VirtualBox: 4.0.12

Any assistance would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**1) Configure the file Vagrantfile**

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
    config.vm.box = "lucid32"
    config.vm.network "33.33.33.10"
    config.vm.forward_port "http", 80, 8080
end
```

**2) Access your VM "lucid32"**

```
vagrant ssh
```

**3) Inside your VM, configure the Apache "Virtual Host":**

```
<VirtualHost 33.33.33.10:80>
    ServerName        your-domain.dev
    DocumentRoot    /vagrant
    DirectoryIndex    index.php index.html index.htm

    <Directory /vagrant>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 33.33.33.10:443>
    ServerName        your-domain.dev
    DocumentRoot    /vagrant
    DirectoryIndex    index.php index.html index.htm

    <Directory /vagrant>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certicate/apache.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

**4) Exit VM and configure the file "hosts" in your host machine:**

```
33.33.33.10    your-domain.dev
```

Comment: When using this solution you have to do steps 2 and 3 over and over again when you destroy the Vagrant box. Using a provisioning (bash) script, Chef or Puppet will make this task a lot less repetitive.

Comment: For googlers, I had to specify both a `SSLCertificateFile` to a `.crt` file and a `SSLCertificateKeyFile` to a `.key` file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above would require you to keep repeating steps 2 and 3 each time you destroy the box. I'd suggest you use Chef to achieve your goal. See the example below:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.box       = "precise64"
    config.vm.box_url   = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 443

    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|

        chef.cookbooks_path = "/path/to/your/cookbooks"

        # Install PHP
        chef.add_recipe "php"
        chef.add_recipe "php::module_mysql"

        # Setup Apache
        chef.add_recipe "apache2"
        chef.add_recipe "apache2::mod_php5"

        chef.json = { :apache => { :default_site_enabled => true } }

    end

end
```