# using SSL on vagrant for drupal VM

Tags: ssl, drupal, vagrant

I am trying to use SSL with apache on vagrant for my Drupal VM

I used that page
http://docs.drupalvm.com/en/latest/extras/ssl/

Added

```
apache_vhosts_ssl:
  - servername: "{{ drupal_domain }}"
    documentroot: "{{ drupal_core_path }}"
    certificate_file: "/vagrant/example.crt"
    certificate_key_file: "/vagrant/example.key"
    extra_parameters: |
          ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000{{ drupal_core_path }}"
```

generated example.crt and example.key
in /vagrant
using `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout example.key -out example.crt`

```
vagrant@name:/vagrant$ ls |grep example
example.crt
example.key
```

I made sure that `443` is open, and I reloaded my machine, but I am still getting

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

When trying to access the page, I do not see any other errors, so I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037497/accessing-apache-on-a-vagrant-sandbox-using-ssl-port-forwarding maybe this can bring to you some help ?

Comment: or this https://aboutssl.org/fix-google-chrome-error-err_ssl_protocol_error

Comment: By reloaded your machine, you mean you also re-provisioned?